# Angular Firebase permission error to access data

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I'm trying to access to the firebase with angular, in my service i've this import :

```
import { AngularFireDatabase , AngularFireList , AngularFireObject } from 'angularfire2/database';
```

And my constructor and get data are like theses :

```
employees : AngularFireList<any>; // what comes from database
Employee : AngularFireObject<any>; // model

  constructor(public af:AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.employees = af.list('/employees') as AngularFireList<Employee>;
   }

   getEmployees(){
     return this.employees;
   }
```

in my component i call the method getEmployees like this :

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getEmployees().valueChanges().subscribe(employees => {
    this.employees = employees;
    console.log(this.employees);
  });
  }
```

When the application run, i've this error in my chrome console :

```
ERROR Error: permission_denied at /employees: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.
```

I've the full access for the Firebase, as you can see here :

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The rules in your question are for firestore, not firebase realtime database....

Answer (score -1):

The rules you have written are for **Firestore** but your code is trying to access the **real-time database**... [Here is the link for the real-time database rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/).

To set the real-time database rules to allow everything, change them to:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": false
  }
}
```

Comment: I've delete the write access, as you can see the syntaxe has changed

Comment: I have the same bug